# Finding patterns in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script to find patterns in a list.

Eg. Given this list

[1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6]

The script would determine that 4,5,6 ocurred 3 times and then print out

3 (4,5,6)

I was hoping if anyone had any insights algorithmically (I can only think of n^2 algorithms where I check for patterns of size 1, then 2, then 3, etc iterating through the string each time) or if there might be any Python built-in libraries which might help do the same things. Thanks!

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you should indicate that.

Comment: having to prove n=np seems a bit harsh for homework.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is not a homework reply, it's a programming problem I'm having in a project. Nothing to prove either, I'm trying to get up with intelligent pseudo-code before I code it up in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I would do this:

1. start with two copies of the list A and B.
2. pop the first value off of B
3. subtract B from A:  C = A-B
4. search for areas in C that are 0; these indicate repeated strings
5. add repeated strings into a dict which tracks each string and the number of times it has been seen
6. repeat steps 2-5 until B is empty.

Comment: and this is not O(n^2) why exactly?

Comment: There is only 1 list which I am trying to find patterns in.....Right, the only algorithm I can think of is an O(n^2) one. Atleast an elegant O(n^2) algorithm would be ok....

Comment: Correct; it is O(n^2). I think the algorithm will only improve if you can constrain it (for example, if you are not interested in repeats separated by long distances).

Comment: I more or less went with this approach, with suggested constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function providing a solution to the pattern matching problem:

```
import itertools

def pattern_match(pattern, sequence):
    """Count the number of times that pattern occurs in the sequence."""
    pattern = tuple(pattern)
    k = len(pattern)

    # create k iterators for the sequence
    i = itertools.tee(sequence, k)

    # advance the iterators
    for j in range(k):
        for _ in range(j):
            next(i[j])

    count = 0
    for q in zip(*i):
        if pattern == q:
            count += 1

    return count
```

To solve the stated problem, call with:

```
p = [4, 5, 6]
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]
count = pattern_match(p, l)
```

Here is a Gist with the complete [code solving the example problem](https://gist.github.com/jcbsv/f92b9e68c1d5f426b7d8).

(I believe the correct answer is that the pattern repeats 4 times, not 3 times, as stated in the question.)

I'm not sure if the complexity of this algorithm is actually less than O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are looking for is [Run Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). The basic principles of that algorithm will give you how to approach detecting patterns in a sequence and counting them.

> Run-length encoding (RLE) is a very simple form of data compression in
>   which runs of data (that is, sequences in which the same data value
>   occurs in many consecutive data elements) are stored as a single data
>   value and count, rather than as the original run.

Here is a relevant article on [how to write an RLE program in Python](http://wordaligned.org/articles/runlength-encoding-in-python).

Comment: @hop yes, I have used the RLE technique to detect repeating patterns in strings of text many times before, you don't need to do the compression part, but the theory behind the RLE is 100% applicable here.

Comment: pure rle assumes that you already know the element in the run while the op sepcifically wants to find such a repeating group.