# Finding patterns in list

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, pattern-matching

I am currently searching for a way to find patterns in a list of integers, but the method I am going to use would be applicable to strings and other lists with different elements of course. Now let me explain what I am looking for.

I want to find the longest repeating pattern in a list of integers. For example,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
# This list would give 1, 2, 3
```

Overlapping patterns should be discarded. ( Not certain )

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# Should give 1, 1  Not 1, 1, 1, 1
```

**Here is what did not help me.**

[Finding patterns in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656310/finding-patterns-in-a-list) (Did not understand the logic behind the first answer, very little explanation. And second answer solves the problem only if the pattern is known before solving.)

[Finding integer pattern from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928775/finding-integer-pattern-from-a-list) (Pattern is given and number of occurrence is wanted. Different than my question.)

[Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) (Most people dealed with this problem however it is not close to mine. I need consecutive elements while searching for a pattern. However in this, seperate elements also counted as subsequences.)

**Here what I tried.**

```
def pattern(seq):
    n = len(seq)
    c = defaultdict(int) # Counts of each subsequence
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, min(n, n / 2 + i)): 
            # Used n / 2 because I figured if a pattern is being searched
            # It cant be longer that the half of the list.
            c[tuple(seq[i:j])] += 1      
    return c
```

As you see, It finds all the sublists and check for repeats. I found this approach a bit naive(and inefficient) and I am in need of a better way. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Note1:** The list is predetermined but because of my algorithms failure, I can only check some parts of the list before freezing the computer. So the pattern I am trying to find can very well be longer than the half of the search list, It can even be longer than the search list itself because I am searching only a part of the original list.If you present a better method than I am using, I can search a larger part of the original list so I will have a better chance at finding the pattern. (If there is one.)

**Note2:** Here is a part of the list if you want to test it yourself. It really seems like that there is a pattern, but I cannot be sure before I test it with a reliable code.
[Sample List](http://collabedit.com/f5j3v)

**Note3:** I approach this as a serious problem of data mining. And will try to learn if you make a long explanation. This feels like a much more important problem than LCS, however LCS is much more popular :D This method I am trying to find feels like the methods scientists use to find DNA patterns.

Comment: What would the result of `[1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2]` be?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26703839/198633

Comment: @dashiell I do not expect such an occurrence in my list however, I guess because both patterns have length 2, the result would be both.

Comment: for [1,1,1,1,1] why the longest repeating pattern is [1,1] rather than [1] which has 5 repetitions

Comment: @k4vin longest repeating pattern, not most frequent.

Comment: [Longest repeated substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem)?

Comment: @Delgan This seems closer to my problem. It includes overlaps. But I will not discard it because maybe the pattern in my list is a overlapped one. Thank you.

Comment: What defines a pattern? Just something a human would notice and seem significant? `1, 2, 3` seems to denote a pattern because we could apply the same mathematical operation to each successive member to generate the next one (`n + 1`). Is `1, 4, 9, 16, 25` a pattern? Each is the square of a consecutive integer, but there's no such mathematical operation using members of the list that could be applied (that is, there's no way to get from the nth member to the (n + 1)th member without a separate list).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Well, what I mean by a pattern is that I expect to list to repeat after some point. So keeping the whole list would be no longer necessary. If I find that *pattern* I need, I will be able to see where the list starts to repeat (if it does).

Comment: Sounds like you definitely are facing the longest repeated subsequence problem then.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist So I have to learn suffix trees ?. Is that a hard subject for a beginner-intermediate programmer ? Well if I must, Then I will.

Comment: You've chosen to work on a problem that's not easy to solve, that's for sure. I don't think there's much to learn in suffix trees except how to construct one. It's just a data structure that's particularly useful for this problem. I don't think there's one built into Python or any third-party lib that would help you make one, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I've seen some third-party one's. But I'd like to implement it using built-ins. Just for this problem.

Answer (score 6):

## The Code (updated for Python 2 + 3)

Ignoring the "no overlapping" requirement, here's the code I used:

```
import collections
  
def pattern(seq):
        storage = {}
        for length in range(1,int(len(seq)/2)+1):
                valid_strings = {}
                for start in range(0,len(seq)-length+1):
                        valid_strings[start] = tuple(seq[start:start+length])
                candidates = set(valid_strings.values())
                if len(candidates) != len(valid_strings):
                        print("Pattern found for " + str(length))
                        storage = valid_strings
                else:
                        print("No pattern found for " + str(length))
                        break
        return set(v for v in storage.values() if list(storage.values()).count(v) > 1)
```

Using that, I found 8 distinct patterns of length 303 in your dataset. The program ran pretty fast, too.

## Pseudocode Version

```
define patterns(sequence):
    list_of_substrings = {}
    for each valid length:  ### i.e. lengths from 1 to half the list's length
        generate a dictionary my_dict of all sub-lists of size length
        if there are repeats:
            list_of_substrings = my_dict
        else:
            return all repeated values in list_of_substrings
    return list_of_substrings  #### returns {} when there are no patterns
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It is clearly faster given that it uses one loop unlike mine, affecting the complexity. I will try this on the list.

Comment: In the pseudocode I used only one loop, but there are two loops in the actual Python implementation. The reason why it's fast is because it uses Python's set() builtin, which hashes the data to quickly check for repetition.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I just missed the second one. Long hours spent on computing problems have effects on the body of course. :(

Comment: I'm trying to run this in Python 3. After using a code convertor and replacing the fist / by // it works. But i'm not that I'm getting the right result at the end...

Comment: @Zumplo I made some changes to make it Python 3 compatible!

Answer (score 0):

This works (without overlapping) but it is for Python 3:

```
def get_pattern(seq):
    seq2 = seq
    outs = {}
    l = 0
    r = 0
    c = None

    for end in range(len(seq2)+1):
      for start in range(end):
          word = chr(1).join(seq2[start:end])
          if not word in outs:
              outs[word] = 1
          else:
              outs[word] += 1
    for item in outs:
        if outs[item] > r or (len(item) > l and outs[item] > 1):
            l = len(item)
            r = outs[item]
            c = item
    return c.split(chr(1))
```